# NullReferenceException error in powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2008, ps1, nagios

I am a newb in power-shell, i have written an script that stops process according to parameters in commandline. the problem is when i run the script in power shell it works but when i try to run it from a remote server using npre even though it find the process i get this error:

```
The retrived Process ID fro test.bat is 9468
Stop-Process : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
At C:\Program Files\NSClient++\scripts\Kill_Java.ps1:14 char:13
+ Stop-Process <<<<  $arman
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Stop-Process], NullReferenceE
xception
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.NullReferenceException,Microsoft.PowerShe
ll.Commands.StopProcessCommand
```

My script is as follow:

```
$servicename=$args[0]


$processid = get-wmiobject -query "select * from win32_process where CommandLine like '%$servicename%' and name='notepad.exe'" | Select-Object Handle | Out-File test.txt



If ((Get-Content "test.txt") -eq $Null) {
"File is blank"
} else {$a = Get-Content test.txt
$arman=$a[3]
write-host The retrived Process ID fro "$servicename" is "$arman"
Stop-Process $arman
}
exit 3
```

I have to add that i am using NSClinet++ to connect to the server and since it is able to retreive the process ID i assume the connection is correct. Please tell me what am i missing ?

Comment: This is the entire script?  It would help if you indicate which line is 14.  What have you done to debug the script?

Comment: Yes this is the entire script and line 14 is (Stop-Process $arman)

Comment: The scripts runs fine from powershell console, it doesn't work when i run it remotely

Comment: Please address my other concerns.

Comment: I have done everything I know, I have tried to set execution policy, Invoke command, nothing seems working. As i said i am a total newb in powershell, when i run my script in local machine it works fine without any problem. even as you can see from the error, it runs from the remote machine, it can find the process ID, just can not stop it. I really think might be from security  permission, but as much as searched i didn't find any concrete answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have Found the solution.

The problem was that NSCLient was using a local authentication, changing the user solved the problem.